# Onslide in tabularx produces vertical space

Tags: tables, beamer, tabularx

I have a tabular in a [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation of which I want to uncover its contents using `\onslide`. In [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (or in `tabular` with a `p`-column) this produces a peculiar vertical white space in the `X`-column. Any ideas about where it comes from and/or how to work around it?

Here is the code I used:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
First line & A very long sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length\\
\onslide<2->{Second line} & \onslide<2->{A slightly longer sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Or with a `p`-column:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
First line & A very long sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length\\
\onslide<2->{Second line} & \onslide<2->{A slightly longer sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. Please always post complete small documents that show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid putting the beamer specials (or any specials) at the start of a parbox:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
First line & A very long sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length\\
\onslide<2->{Second line} & \leavevmode\onslide<2->{A slightly longer sentence that takes up more than one line because of its length} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the problem although I need some more time to see why exactly.

Comment: @RonnieHermens `p` columns line up on the top "row" but in vertical mode the special comes _above_ the row of text so it lines on that. the modified code puts the special inside (at the start of) the first row of text so the first item in the parbox is that line and things work better. You get the same with color or any other special.